# git commit -a "My comment" not working

Tags: git

I can make a commit with git with the following command:

```
git commit -a
```

However then I have to enter the comment with VIM. Id rather do it all with one command so ive tried the following:

```
git commit -a "My comment"
```

But then I get this message:

```
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want

```
git commit -m "My comment"
```

or

```
git commit -am "My comment"
```

to combine the `a` (all) and the `m` (comment message) parameters.

Comment: also check `git commit --help`, just for fun

Answer (score 0):

Add your modified & added files: `git add -A`, then commit your changes: `git commit -m "your message"`